# What does "Grace be with you" mean in 1 Timothy 6:21?

Tags: 1-timothy

"...some have swerved from the faith. Grace be with you". 1 Timothy 6:21 ESV

Do any of these give the meaning of the Greek? :

A. Grace be/is with you. I have every confidence it is yours, yours already.

B. "Grace be with you". I hope God is going to give it to you. Encouragement.

C. "Grace be with you". As the Holy Spirit's servant I am bestowing grace on you.

D. "may" [implied] grace be with you. We say "may X pass their exam". Showing sympathy may not actually help them to pass.

E. "Grace" has much emphasis on it, as it is central to this concluding thought of the whole letter. Does it have the article [in Greek] to make it more emphatic?

Comment: It is usually taken as a Christianized Hebraism equivalent to "Shalom."

Comment: Could "grace be with you" in that context simply mean: "may it not happen to you"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the last words in 1 Timothy 6:

> 21b Grace be with you.

The phrase serves as a concise benediction from Paul.
"Grace" means "divine favour". Paul was blessing them with divine favour as the last thing in this epistle.

Interesting, Paul opened his next letter with
2 Timothy 1

> 1 Paul, an apostle of Christ Jesus by the will of God, in keeping with the promise of life that is in Christ Jesus,
>
> 2To Timothy, my dear son:
>
> **Grace**, mercy and **peace** from God the Father and Christ Jesus our Lord.

Here grace and peace are clearly separated as distinct.
As well, in
Romans 1:

> 7  To all those in Rome who are loved by God and called to be saints: **Grace** to you and **peace** from God our Father and the Lord Jesus Christ.

Ellicott:

> Grace . . . and peace.—May God and Christ look favourably upon you, and may you enjoy, as the result of that favour, the peace and composure of mind which is the proper attribute of the Christian.
>
> The terms “grace” and “peace” nearly correspond to two ordinary forms of Jewish salutation, the first of which has also something of a counterpart among the Greeks and Romans. But here, as elsewhere, the Apostle has given to them a **heightened** and **deepened** Christian signification. **Grace** is the peculiar state of **favour** with God and Christ, into which the sincere Christian is admitted. **Peace** is the state of **mind** resulting from the sense of that **favour**.

Peace follows after grace in a way that is better than the corresponding Hebraisms.

Answer (score 1):

Ἡ χάρις μεθʼ ὑμῶν (NA28) is a greeting in the form of a blessing in Greek.  It acknowledges our dependence on God's grace to accomplish his work.  It is accompanied by a humble attitude toward sinners and thankfulness, "But there by the grace of God go I." As well as Κύριε, ἐλέησον, "Lord, have mercy."

> **Grace be with you**. This benediction is Paul’s “trademark,” because only God’s grace can keep His people on the “strait and narrow” way. Amen
> --
> MacDonald, W. (1995). Believer’s Bible Commentary: Old and New Testaments. (A. Farstad, Ed.) (pp. 2103–2104). Nashville: Thomas Nelson.

Many commentators mentioned that the 2nd person plural pronoun indicated that the letter address to Timothy was intended to be read by churches.

> TEXT

> 21b.μεθʼ ὑμῶν (א* A F G 33 81 g bomss): μετά σου (D [K L] Ψ 048 1739 1881 TR lat sy bomss). Elliott, 110f., argues that the sing. form, which is consistent with the rest of the Epistle (cf. especially 6:20), was generalised by scribes; Metzger, 577, however, states that the pl. is adequately supported and was changed to fit the rest of letter.
> At the end of the letter: add ἀμήν (א2 D1 Ψ 1739c TR f vgcl ww sy bo Ambst). The addition is rejected by Elliott, 104; Metzger, 577 (cf. Tit 3:15).
> --
> Marshall, I. H., & Towner, P. H. (2004). A critical and exegetical commentary on the Pastoral Epistles (p. 679). London; New York: T&T Clark International.

In the sense of *good will* it is similar to Jesus' Hebrew/Aramaic greeting his disciples in John 20:19.

> שָׁלוֹם לָכֶם (meaning well being; the peace that passes understanding, Philippians 4:6)

> εἰρήνη ὑμῖν (NA28)

> Peace be with you (ESV)